# Running Magento 2 via FastCGI (not mod_php) on OS X via brew Packages

Tags: magento2, php

Based on various forum postings and conversations in the community, it seems like some folks are running Magento 2 development instances on OS X via a PHP environment that doesn't use the built-in Apache/PHP combo and instead uses packages from `brew` to get a FastCGI PHP environment up and running with `nginx` and/or `apache`.

Does anyone have a list of commands and configuration instructions for getting Magento 2 up and running on OS X **using brew packages** OR some other means for running PHP in a FastCGI environment on OS X?  I'm not looking for Docker or Vagrant -- I want to run PHP natively on OS X and dont want to use `mod_php`.

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful, but I was never a Fan of brew so I always installed PHP to use natively from https://php-osx.liip.ch/

Comment: @mhauri If you have instructions for getting the php-fpm from the liip packages running a full answer would be great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apache + PHP-FPM with Homebrew

**Step 0: Before we start**

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/services
```

**Step 1: Apache**

1.- Let's make sure to stop the build-in apache service

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
sudo apachectl stop
```

2.- Install apache2.4

```
brew install homebrew/apache/httpd24 --with-privileged-ports
```

***This step will take a while since it has to compile Apache.***

3.- Verify it was installed correctly, you should see a message similar to:

> To have launchd start homebrew/apache/httpd24 now and restart at
>   startup:   sudo brew services start homebrew/apache/httpd24

Let's run the command:

```
sudo brew services start homebrew/apache/httpd24
```

Verify everything is running by loading, http://localhost after which we should see the **It Works!** message
[image: It Works]

**Step 2: PHP-FPM**

1.- Let's continue by installing PHP

```
brew install -v homebrew/php/php70
```

2.- Start PHP-FPM, the beauty about homebrew/php is that it installs PHP and FPM, so we only need to run the following:

```
brew services start homebrew/php/php70
```

For now let's use the default configuration, if we need to change it the configuration is located at ***/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/***

Step 3: Configuration

1.- Open the Apache configuration:

```
vim /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf
```

2.- Uncomment the following lines:

```
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
```

3.- Setup the proxy config for PHP-FPM:

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/var/www/htdocs/$1
</IfModule>
```

***Typically I would setup this per vhost to point it to the right directory***

4.- Finally let's create a phpinfo() page inside **/usr/local/var/www/htdocs/** and confirm everything is working by loading the test page:
[image: We have php]

There are a few more tweaks and turns, but this should get you up and running directly on OSX.

For a more detailed walkthrough of the configuration we use check the configuration(vhost, php pools, etc) on this vagrant box:

https://github.com/DemacMedia/vagrant-lamp/tree/master/files

Comment: I had to a `brew install homebrew/apache/httpd24 --with-privileged-ports` instead of a `brew install httpd24 --with-privileged-ports`.  Does that match your real world experience?

Comment: @AlanStorm I followed the same procedure but some how .htaccess is creating an issue while loading Magento's index.php. It does not let the page open however if I remove .htaccess from root folder then atleast Magento opens which again gets distorted for reasons.
Could you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 10):

1. Follow one of the many Mac + Nginx + PHP-FPM + Mysql setup tutorials like this (be sure to use `brew services`):

   - https://gist.github.com/dtomasi/ab76d14338db82ec24a1fc137caff75b
   - https://gist.github.com/johnantoni/07df65898456ace4307d5bb6cbdc7f51
2. `brew install php70-intl php70-mcrypt`
3. In `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` inside `http` define new upstream

   ```
   upstream fastcgi_backend {
     server  127.0.0.1:9070;
   }
   ```

   `9000` is the default port, but I'd recommend to add PHP version number as a last two digits, to be able to use few versions of PHP at the same time i.e. for M1. You can modify FPM port in file `/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.d/www.conf` - `listen = 127.0.0.1:9070` and then restart PHP using `brew services restart php70`.
4. Copy `nginx.conf.sample` form M2 repository and save as `/usr/local/etc/nginx/magento2.conf`. This config will use `fastcgi_backend` defined in the previous step.
5. Setup vhosts and domains

   ```
   server {
     listen 80;
     server_name magento2.dev;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /path/to/m2/project;
     set $MAGE_MODE developer;
     include /usr/local/etc/nginx/magento2.conf;
   }
   ```
6. Restart Nginx

Comment: that first gist asks you to tap homebrew/dupes, which is depreciated and will (if I recall) no longer give you the formulae you need. 

*Warning: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated*

Comment: Looks like `dupes` are now part of the core, so you can just ignore it and stick with `brew tap homebrew/php` only.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Followed Magento setup but for Ubuntu and line 'listen = /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock' was causing me sooo much problems. All I needed is not to add that just to use:
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000 and change it to listen = 127.0.0.1:9071 if I wanted to use multi PHP version. Spent ages looking for a solutions.

Answer (score 10):

**Step 1 : Stop the existing apache service and install Apache thru Brew.**

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
$ brew install httpd24 --with-privileged-ports --with-http2
```

This step takes a little while as it builds Apache from source. Upon completion you should see a message like:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.23_2: 212 files, 4.4M, built in 1 minute 60 seconds
```

**Step 2 : This is important because you will need that path in the next step.**

```
$ sudo cp -v /usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.23_2/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons

$ sudo chown -v root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist

$ sudo chmod -v 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist

$ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist
```

Now we have installed  Homebrew's Apache, and configured it to auto-start with a privileged account.

Server can be reached **http://localhost**

**Step 3 : Apache Configuration**

Configuration file Path

```
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf
```

if you want to change the configuration , you should make it here

**Note :** we should now enable mod_rewrite which is commented out by default.

LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so

For Magento installation mod_rewrite should be enable in this configuration file.

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

**Step 4 :  PHP installation**

we can get a full list of available options to include by typing

```
$ brew install php71 --with-httpd24
```

We can choose which version we are going to use.

For configure the tweak configuration setting of PHP for our needs for example , memory_limit, date.timezone, display_errors...etc/apache2/2

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
```

**Step 5 : Apache PHP Setup**

Now we have successfully installed your PHP versions, but we need to tell Apache to use them . we need to edit apache configuration file

```
/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf
```

by modifying the php path.

```
LoadModule php7_module    /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Handle the php requests in apache by the following configuration needs to be modified

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Save the configuration file and restart the apache.

```
$ sudo apachectl -k restart
```

**Step 6 : Validating PHP**

create an php file info.php in document root directory

Content of info.php is

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

**Step 6 : Check the dependency extension of  PHP for Magento  in php.ini file.**

Required PHP extensions for Magento2:

```
bc-math 
curl
gd, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both
intl
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
openssl
PDO/MySQL
SimpleXML
soap
xml
xsl
zip
PHP 7 only:
json
iconv
```

Then you can proceed with Magento installation.

Answer (score 5):

1. Install PHP 7:

   ```
   brew install php70-intl php70-mcrypt php70-xdebug
   ```
2. You can then use Laravel Valet to automate the Nginx+PHP-FPM install: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet

   ```
   composer global require laravel/valet
   valet install
   ```
3. Create a project directory if you don't already have one (can be named whatever you want)

   ```
   mkdir ~/projects
   ```
4. Tell Laravel Valet that you store your projects there

   ```
   cd ~/projects
   valet park
   ```
5. At time of this post the version of Laravel Valet that contains the Magento2 driver has not yet been released (it has been [merged](https://github.com/laravel/valet/pull/147), but not yet released via a tag).  To use it you can either:

   - Install Laravel Valet via the dev-master branch:

     ```
     composer global require laravel/valet:dev-master`
     ```
   - or download the driver and use it as a local Valet driver:

     ```
     curl https://github.com/laravel/valet/raw/master/cli/drivers/Magento2ValetDriver.php -o ~/.valet/Drivers/Magento2ValetDriver.php
     ```

You can now browse to `http://[projectname].dev/` to see your local project (where [projectname] corresponds to a directory in ~/projects. eg:

```
~/projects/my-super-awesome-client => my-super-awesome-client.dev
```

**FULL DISCLOSURE:** I am one of the authors of the Magento2 driver for Laravel Valet

Comment: It's possible that I'm being quite dense, but these steps seem incomplete (e.g. `valet link`ing, nginx m2 setup...). Am I overthinking this?

Comment: The valet park takes care of the linking. As long as you "park" in your projects directory and each project is a sub directory containing an M2 install, there is nothing more to do. The Magento2 driver for valet takes care of everything so that Valet knows how to server an M2 site (so no additional nginx config needed). Yes, it really is that simple. Valet was built to remove the pain of setting up Laravel sites. They made it possible to use it for non-Laravel projects as well so everyone wins

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Valet+](https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus) instead configuring it on your own, b/c it's automated bare-metal Mac OS solution based on Homebrew packages.
Setup steps and other things are described on [Github](https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus).

Blog post about it - [Introducing Valet+, Blazing fast PHP development environment](https://medium.com/@timneutkens/introducing-valet-blazing-fast-php-development-environment-46be91604bb2)